# Call Method with parameters from another class

Tags: java, list, arraylist, methods, parameters

```
package com.test.game;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;

public class Card {
    private static String[] colours = new String[]{"E", "L", "H", "S"};
    private static String[] cardValues = new String[]{"7", "8", "9", "10", "B", "D", "K", "A"};
    private String cardValue;
    private String colour;

    private Card(String cardValue, String colour) {
        this.cardValue = cardValue;
        this.colour = colour;
    }





    public String toString() {
        return cardValue + colour;
    }



    static void CardDeck() {
        ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
        for (int i = 0; i < colours.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cardValues.length; j++) {
                cards.add(new Card(cardValues[j], colours[i]));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(cards);


    }
    static void Collections(ArrayList<Card> cards, int seed){
        Collections.shuffle(cards, new Random(seed));
        System.out.println(cards);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println();
    }



}
```

```
package com.test.game;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Game {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Card.CardDeck();
        Card.Collections();

    }
}
```

So I am working on a card game right now. The first class creates an array list containing cards with the help of the method `CardDeck()` this method gets called in the Game class and that works perfectly fine. Now in the Method Collections() this array list is supposed to be shuffled. So that the cards are in a random order.

Therefore I have 2 questions. First is the way I am shuffling the cards right? And how can I call this `Collectinons()`method in another class? Due to the fact that it has parameters it does not work. I have found some similar questions but they did not really work for me. (creating a new instance)

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of printing the list in `CardDeck` (that you should rename to `cardDeck`), just return the deck, so that the caller can use it:

```
static List<Card> cardDeck() {
    ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
    for (int i = 0; i < colours.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cardValues.length; j++) {
            cards.add(new Card(cardValues[j], colours[i]));
        }
    }
    return cards;
}
```

You can then pass it to your method `Collections` (that you should rename to `shuffle`):

```
static void shuffle(List<Card> cards, int seed){
    Collections.shuffle(cards, new Random(seed));
}
```

And don't print it there: the caller can always print it afterwards.

Your `main` method becomes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Card> deck = Card.cardDeck();
    Card.shuffle(deck, whatever);
    System.out.println(deck);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice but I am still not abble to call the shuffle method. When I try to call it from the Game class with `Card.shuffle();` the `()` get underline by IntelliJ. The error says `'shuffle(java.util.ArrayList<com.test.game.Card>, int)' in 'com.test.game.Card' cannot be applied to '()'

Comment: ahhh no nevermind it worked thanks you!

Comment: And another question. If I have to use a return at cardDeck(). How am I supposed to print it out in my other class. When I do the same as in shuffle() it says that I need a parameter in cardDeck() but I dont want one.

Comment: @KepaArizzabalaga `System.out.println(deck);`

Comment: @KepaArizzabalaga you have your deck; just print it.